# Necesito sacar una suma y promedio

Tags: php, mysql

En mi base de datos guardo eventos como ejemplo (`evento a` , `evento b`,...) , estos eventos los convierto a un numero entero entre `0-100` de esta manera

```
a = 10,
b = 20,
c = 50,
d = 100,
```

Para ubicar que evento se encuentra dentro del mapa que trabajo utilizo los polígonos y ubico los puntos con un `ST_CONTAINS` y para saber los eventos que se encuentran dentro de cada poligono utilizo un `GROUP_CONCAT`

Este es un ejemplo

```
select idmapa,GROUP_CONCAT(tipo) from mapa , evento where ST_CONTAINS(geometria, Direccion) group by idmapa
```

Lo que necesito es que los eventos que sean convertidos a esos números y puedan sumar y sacar promedio para cada polígono ,y sacarlo esto en mi servidor php , lo intente con `foreach` pero no saca el promedio  para cada poligono sino suma el de todos y ya voy semanas sufriendo intentando muchas formas pero lo hago mal nesecito ayuda :( ,si alguien tiene una solucion se lo agradeceria muchisimo.

Mi codigo en Php es el siguiente :

Ya conectado con mi base de datos  haciendo un select para que encuentre mis  puntos donde ingrese los eventos que pertenezcan a un poligono dentro de mi mapa

```
$sql ="select idmapa,GROUP_CONCAT(tipo) from mapa , evento where ST_CONTAINS(geometria, Direccion) group by idmapa";
    $result = $link->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($data = $result->fetch_assoc()){


 if($data['GROUP_CONCAT(tipo)']=='A') {
    $peso[1] = 20;
    }
    elseif ($data['GROUP_CONCAT(tipo)'] =='B' ){
    $peso [2] = 30;
    }
    elseif ($data['GROUP_CONCAT(tipo)'] =='C'){ 
    $peso [3] = 35;
    }
    elseif ($data['GROUP_CONCAT(tipo)'] =='D'){
    $peso [4] = 40;
    }
    elseif ($data['GROUP_CONCAT(tipo)'] =='E'){
    $peso [5] = 50;
    }
    elseif ($data['GROUP_CONCAT(tipo)'] =='F'){ 
    $peso [6] = 60;
    }
    elseif ($data['GROUP_CONCAT(tipo)'] =='G'){ 
    $peso[7] = 70;
    }
    elseif ($data['GROUP_CONCAT(tipo)'] =='H'){ 
    $peso [8] = 100;
    }
    else {
    $peso [9] = 0;
    }


    $suma =  0;

    foreach ($peso as $numero=> $val) {
        $suma += $val;

        }



    $cantidadDeElementos = count($peso);

    $promedio=$suma / $cantidadDeElementos;
    $idencontrado=$data['idmapa'];
```

Con esto hago una sentencia para actualizar un promedio a cada poligono ,para cada id

```
    $sql2 ="UPDATE `mapa` SET `promedio`={$promedio} WHERE `idmapa`={$idencontrado};";}
```

Agradecería si me indican los errores tal vez la respuesta es muy simple o no lo veo :(  .

Lo que sale en mi taba al hacer el primer select es esto

```
idmapa  GROUP_CONCAT(tipo)  / LO QUE SERIA =
1        A,B,C               10+20+30
2        B,A,A,C             20+10+10+30
3        C,A                 30+10
4        A                   10
```

.
.

y si le agrego la fila de promedio quisiera que me devuelva asi

```
idmapa  GROUP_CONCAT(tipo)  promedio
1        A,B,C               20
2        B,A,A,C             17,5
3        C,A                 20
4        A                   10
```

Comment: ¿Puedes subir el código con el que haces las sumas?, porfavor

Comment: O mejor aún. Cuál es el resultado que esperas recibir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Franks,
Sigue una sugerencia.Yo trabajaria con dos tablas.

1 - Tabla mapa_grupo 
    Tipo peso
    A     10
    B     20
    c     30

2 - Tabla mapa
    idmapa    tipo
     1         A
     1         B
     1         C

3 - Debes agregar el peso 
[image: Resultado de promedio]

4 - Ejemplo final

```
SELECT IDMAPA,GROUP_CONCAT(G.PESO),COUNT(G.PESO)CANTIDAD,(SUM(G.PESO)/COUNT(G.PESO))AS PROMEDIO
FROM MAPA M
INNER JOIN MAPA_GRUPO G ON M.TIPO = G.TIPO
GROUP BY IDMAPA
```

5 - Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado lleva en cuenta hubo inserciones en la tabla id_
Ejemplo:

```
idmapa  tipo    
------  --------
     1  A       
     1  B       
     1  C       
     2  B       
     2  A       
     2  A       
     2  C       
     3  C       
     3  A       
     4  A
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias , me ayudo muchisimo lo malo es que me aparecio un problema , al momento de llevarlo a mi php para actualizarlo solo colocando la sentencia sql lo hace ok , coloca todo los promedio pero pasa un determinado tiempo y el promedio se convierte en el ultimo valor

Comment: Franks,
ponga tu código que estas utilizando para grabar los datos para que otras personas puedan ayudarlo.
Aclare em que punto está ocorriendo los cambios del promedio.

Comment: Franks, sin conocer el proceso de como e cuando la tabla debe ser actualizada y aún sin conocer las tablas no nos deja espacio para ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias Bonfim ya resolvi el problema era que otro codigo estaba interfiriendo con la base de datos , con tu ayuda pude resolver mi problema , te lo agradezco :) .